# How many ways can the letters ABCDEFG be arranged such that A and B are never next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The problem (not homework) is: How many ways can the letters ABCDEFG be arranged such that A and B are never next to each other?

I couldn't find a quick formula for this, so I ended up doing it by intuition (I don't know if my answer is correct, hoping for some confirmation).

If the letter "A" is in the first spot, there are $5$ spots where "B" can go such that it's not next to "A". If "A" is in the second to sixth spots, there are $4$ possible spots each for "B" to be placed. $(5 \cdot 4) = 20$ total spots. If "A" is in the seventh spot, there are again $5$ possible spots for "B". So there are a total of $30$ rearrangements of "A" and "B" in $7$ spots where they aren't next to each other.

For every placement of "A" and "B", the $5$ other letters can be rearranged $120$ times ($5!$) such that they form different 'words' without moving the "A" and "B", so I multiplied the $30$ rearrangements of "A" and "B" by $120$ and got $3600$. Can anyone confirm or give a formula for this?

Comment: Do you know how to count the number of permutations of this "word" where $A$ and $ B$ are next to one another?

Comment: im not totally sure, but im sure i can just count them out. i don't know the formula for it

Comment: Think about $\{AB\}$ as its own unit which you can permute in $2!$ different ways. Do you see how with this interpretation there must be $6!\cdot 2!$ ways we can permute this "word" keeping $A$ and $B$ adjacent? This immediately implies there ars $7! - 2!\cdot 6!$ ways we can permute this "word" keeping $A$ and $B$ apart.

Comment: that makes it so much clearer. thank you!!!

Comment: @MatthewPilling  You should write up your comment as a solution so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can arrange CDEFG in $5!=120$ ways, with $6$ spaces in between them and at the ends. Choose one of these spaces for A and another for B; makes $120\cdot6\cdot5=3600$ in total.